# Subversion: how to remove property on commit

Tags: svn, properties, pre-commit-hook

My situation is this: I have a Subversion server set up at my home, and we also use Subversion at the company where I work.

At work, we use the lock/edit/unlock model (mainly because we are transitioning from Visual SourceSafe and it's easier for the moment). At the moment this is achieved by setting the 'needs-lock' property on all added files (using the auto-props section of the SVN client config file on each client machine).

However, I don't want to use this model for my home SVN server (I prefer the edit/merge/commit way of working), so currently after I commit anything from my work PC to my home server, I have to manually remove the needs-lock property from any files I have added.

Is there a way I can set up the SVN client to only apply this property to files committed to a particular server? Or am I going about it the wrong way: should I be using hooks on the work server to add this property, instead of the client?

Any help or advice is much appreciated.

EDIT: Apparently, you cannot do this on the server (or at least it's extremely strongly recommended that you don't).

Comment: YUCK!  Start fighting at work to get this changed!

Comment: The worst part is, I set it up...

Comment: That's usually how it goes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subversion autoprops feature is configured in the [config](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config) file of your SVN client. There is also a separate [servers](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.servers) configuration file that supports server-specific settings, but unfortunately you cannot override autoprops there.

I suggest you make two versions of config: *config.home* and *config.work*. Then write a shell script (e.g. a .bat file) that copies one of those over *config*. That should allow you to switch quickly and easily between both configurations.

Answer (score 10):

I also wrote a little Windows batch file to recursively remove the `needs-lock` property from any folders where it had already been set. Put these lines into a text file:

```
svn propdel svn:needs-lock -R -q "%1"
svn commit "%1" -m "Removed needs-lock"
```

Save it as `remove-needs-lock.bat`, and add it's location to your PATH environment variable. Then you can run:

```
remove-needs-lock c:\workingcopyfoldername
```

And presto, all the files no longer require lock to edit.